# Java: How can I "store" a getter in a variable?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following scenario: I have a class:

```
public class A {
  
  private B b;
  private C c;
  private D d;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Each of those classes which are fields of class A has (among others) a method which returns a string.

```
public class B {
  
  private String name;

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  .
  .
  .

}
```

In my UI there is a data view which displays instances of class A. I would like to make it possible for the user to choose what this overview displays. Ex they want to see the value of C instead of D.

Now I could just hack this together with if-else statements but there must be a better way to do this. What I'd like to do is simply be able to store a variable which then tells my view which method provides the value to display. How would I do that? When googling I found a couple examples using `Supplier` however this (as far as I understood) can only be used for specific instances of a class.

Comment: Use a Function: `Function<B, String> f = B::getName;`

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for your answer. If I do that, I get the error that "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: A supplier is exactly what you are looking for: `Supplier<String> get = () -> activeClass.getName();`. But to me it seems this problem should be solved using an interface or abstract class depending on your needs.